# Realm DB - how many migrations are possible?

Tags: reactjs, migration, realm, native

I have a specific use-case where I will need to alter a database schema frequently. I am trying to decide between deleting and re-creating the entire realm, or just deleting objects, migrating, and re-creating the objects within the original realm.

Is there a hard limit to the number of migrations possible with a realm? Any other issues with using migrations in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, schema version is defined as `uint64_t` (unsigned 64 bit integer). Therefore migration limit value is at least less than `18446744073709551615`.